# Select the highest record of each relation

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I need to get the most visited site of all users

I have the following tables:

page:

```
id link_page
1  link 1
2  link 2
3  Link 3
```

user:

```
id name
1 Joseph
2 Cris
3 Byram
```

pages_user:

```
  user_id  page_id
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
     2         1
     2         1
     2         2
```

Should obtain the following:

```
user_id | most visited page id
 1              1
 2              1
```

So far I did something like this:

```
SELECT count(pu.page_id) as counter, pu.user_id 
FROM page_user pu
INNER JOIN page p on p.id = pu.page_id
INNER JOIN users u on u.id = pu.user_id
GROUP BY pu.user_id, pu.page_id 
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

But I return all the records.

As I can get the site most visited of all users?

Greetings from Chile.

Comment: You only need `GROUP BY pu.user_id`

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Unfortunately no use me that way, as the query tells me all the records for each user and I just need to get the most visited page of each user. Greetings !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
  t.user_id,
  t.page_id AS most_visited_page_id
FROM (
      SELECT 
        pu.user_id,
        pu.page_id,
        COUNT(*) AS visitCount
      FROM page_user pu
        INNER JOIN page p ON p.id = pu.page_id
        INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = pu.user_id
      GROUP BY pu.user_id, pu.page_id
      ORDER BY pu.user_id, visitCount DESC, rand() <-- In case of multiple
                          page with same count it will give random page or you can check 
                          it with most recent visit with date if any -->

    ) AS t
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d8a3/8).

Comment: `order by  rand()` is killer and its one of the way to kill the performance.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty It is. But added for tie case to randomly select a page.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, was very useful to me your answer was exactly what I wanted. Greetings from Chile and good day for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, (SELECT page_id FROM page_user 
WHERE user_id = id GROUP BY page_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(page_id) DESC  LIMIT 1) FROM USER
```

Try this query . You may modify to show all required fields

EDIT : To see the number of hits, use the following query.

```
SELECT id, (SELECT page_id FROM page_user 
WHERE user_id = id GROUP BY page_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(page_id) DESC  LIMIT 1) page_id, (SELECT COUNT(page_id) cnt FROM page_user 
WHERE user_id = id GROUP BY page_id 
ORDER BY cnt DESC  LIMIT 1) cnt FROM USER
```

Comment: I work but there is no way to make the count (pu.page_id) to know how many times that page was visited ?. Thank you very much for your help. Greetings !!

Comment: @CristianMezaBustos I have updated the answer to incorporate your requirement. please check it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it, consider the following

```
mysql> select * from user;
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | Joseph |
|    2 | Cris   |
|    3 | Byam   |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from page;
+------+-----------+
| id   | link_page |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | link 1    |
|    2 | link 2    |
|    3 | link 3    |
+------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+---------+---------+
| user_id | page_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       2 |       2 |
|       3 |       2 |
|       3 |       2 |
|       3 |       2 |
|       3 |       1 |
|       3 |       3 |
|       3 |       3 |
+---------+---------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)


select 
u.id as user_id,
p.id as `most visited page id`
from user u join ( 
  select count(*) as cnt,user_id,page_id from pages_user group by user_id,page_id
)x on x.user_id = u.id 
left join(
 select count(*) as cnt,user_id,page_id from pages_user group by user_id,page_id
)y on x.user_id = y.user_id and y.cnt > x.cnt
join page p on p.id = x.page_id 
where y.user_id is null ;

+---------+----------------------+
| user_id | most visited page id |
+---------+----------------------+
|       1 |                    1 |
|       2 |                    1 |
|       3 |                    2 |
+---------+----------------------+
```

Comment: What if one user has visited two page same no. of times?

Comment: @Beginner good question, in that case both of them would be listed using the above approach since from the spec its not clear what would decide the higher weight in case of tie.

Comment: Or we can group the outer select with `u.id` and use `group_concat` for `p.id`?

Comment: yes you can do anything with the returned data using a outer select. Also can set some ranking mechanism but this will make the query over complicated.